# Laravel Soft Delete restore() Error

Tags: laravel, eloquent, soft-delete

The following soft delete code works fine for me:

```
$post = Post::find($post_id);
$post->delete();
```

The deleted_at field is updated. But this gives me an error:

```
$post = Post::find($post_id);
$post->restore();
```

Here's the error:

```
exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to a member function restore() on a non-object'
```

I'm stumped. Google is no help so far.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Error says `$post` is a non-object, Laravel doesn't return trashed records without `withTrashed()`

```
Post::withTrashed()->find($post_id)->restore();
```

[Laravel Docs - Soft Deleting](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#soft-deleting)

> When querying a model that uses soft deletes, the "deleted" models will not be included...

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to search through the trashed models for a specific ID:

```php
Post::onlyTrashed()->where('id', $post_id)->restore();
```

Comment: Review: Adding some comment and explanation with your answer would be nice.

Comment: khalid, is your insight here to point out that withTrashed is unnecessary when you know you're looking for trashed values? if so it could be good to clarify that.

Comment: withTrashed use for recuperate post deleted and post not deleted ,onlytrashed use for recuperate only post deleted

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be of use to someone in the future. You can easily use restore when on the routing we also download with deleted ones.

```
Route::post('restore/{exampleModel}', [ExampleController::class, 'restore'])->withTrashed();
```

```
public function restore(ExampleModel $exampleModel)
{
        $exampleModel->restore();
}
```